# How to bind HTML data in JSON property in Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

My JSON looks like:

```
[
  {
    "Title": "MyTitle1",
    "Content": "<p>Content1</p>",
    "Date": "2014-11-19T10:00:00"
  },
  {
    "Title": "MyTitle2",
    "Content": "<p>Content2</p>",
    "Date": "2014-11-19T00:00:00"
  }
]
```

I'm getting it in my controller like this:

```
app.controller('NewsfeedCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get(serverAddress + '/api/newsfeed/page/1').
      success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          $scope.newsfeeds = data;
      }).
      error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          console.log("Smth went wrong.");
      });
});
```

And bind it in view:

```
<div ng-controller="NewsfeedCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="newsfeed in newsfeeds">
        {{newsfeed.Title}}
        <br />-
        <br />{{newsfeed.Date}}
        <br />-
        {{newsfeed.Content}}
    </div>
</div>
```

But if I have HTML tags in Content, how can I have it also binded to view with that tags parsed.

Comment: Use ng-bind-html for newsfeed.Content, this way content will be handled as html code, not as plain text. Also you should include ngSanitize module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ng-bind-html` to handle content as html content.

```
<div ng-controller="NewsfeedCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="newsfeed in newsfeeds">
        {{newsfeed.Title}}
        <br />-
        <br />{{newsfeed.Date}}
        <br />-
        <div ng-bind-html="newsfeed.Content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also don't forget to include `ngSanitize` module in your application like this.

```
angular.module('itadPortal', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize']);
```

You can read more about ng-bind-html [HERE](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml).

Comment: I have one module: var app = angular.module('itadPortal', ['ngRoute']); and start every controller with it. How can I add second module to it?

Answer (score 0):

With [`ngBindHtml`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml):

```
<span ng-bind-html="newsfeed.Content"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loading the HTML tags as part of Content, just replace them with the name (e.g. just "Content2") and load them inside a p tag. So your JSON would look like:

```
[
  {
    "Title": "MyTitle1",
    "Content": "Content1",
    "Date": "2014-11-19T10:00:00"
  },
  {
    "Title": "MyTitle2",
    "Content": "Content2",
    "Date": "2014-11-19T00:00:00"
  }
]
```

and your view should contain this line:

```
<p> {{newsFeed.content}} </p>
```